# how to efficiently apply function to all pairs of a set (and collect the results)

Tags: list-manipulation, map, sets

To build a graph, I need to apply a function `f[a_, b_]` to all pairs of a list (3500 elements). The function itself returns a link `{a <-> b}` if a particular relation holds - I collect all the results into a list and use it as input to `Graph[]`.

The question is: is there an efficient and elegant way to do this? I've tried two ways: a recursive method and a (similar) iterative method. The former went over the usual recursion limits, the latter was slow and (I believe) not the optimal way to do it.

Both of these performed by applying `f[]` to the `First[]` element vs. the 2nd, 3rd, ...`Last[]` elements, and collecting the results. Then I'd remove the `First[]` from the list, and repeat - doing n*(n-1)/2 evaluations of `f[]`. This many evaluations is required, but I definitely do not have a clean, functional implementation.

So, in short, if this can be turned into an efficient 1-liner, instead of a loop, please do let me know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks all for the great, instructive answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two built-in functions to generate pairs, either with ([`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)) or without ([`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html)) duplication.  Since your question states the number of iterations as $n*(n-1)/2$ I believe you want the latter:

```
set = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Subsets[set, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
> ```

The short notation for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at [level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/levels-how-do-they-work) 1 is `@@@`, so this gives `f` for each pair:

```
f @@@ Subsets[set, {2}]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[2, 3], f[2, 4], f[3, 4]}
> ```

This is in my opinion the most elegant code to produce this specific result, and it is quite fast, but it is not memory efficient if you only need to collect a result for a low percentage of the pairs.  Let's define `f` as follows (I use `{}` here generically):

```
f[a_, b_] /; b~Divisible~a := {a, b}

f[___] = Sequence[];
```

If we now compute all the pairs for `Range[5000]` it takes one gigabyte of memory:

```
pairs = Range@5000 ~Subsets~ {2};
pairs // ByteCount
```

> 1099780032

And applying `f` we see that of the nearly 12.5 million pairs we need a return for only 38376 of them which takes only 3MB of storage:

```
r1 = f @@@ pairs;

ByteCount[r1]

Length[r1]
```

> 3377120
>
> 38376

Yet, the maximum memory used is 1.6GB:

```
 MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 1629793536

A simple method to reduce memory consumption is to process the subsets in blocks, rather than all at once, as follows:

```
set = Range@5000;
n = Length@set;
max = n (n - 1)/2;
block = 10000;

Timing[
 r2 =
   Join @@ Array[
     f @@@ Subsets[set, {2}, block {# - 1, #} + {1, 0}] &,
     ⌈max/block⌉
   ];
]

Length[r2]

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> {8.299, Null}
>
> 38376
>
> 19769800

This only uses a maximum of ~20MB of memory, only a few MB over the baseline on my system.
(It issues a `Subsets::take` message but there is no error.)

#### My preferred method

Another method, and the one that I prefer, is to compute the pairs more manually allowing `f` to be embedded in the process so as to not generate all pairs beforehand.  This uses `Outer` to effect the pair generation for each element separately (that is, all pairs starting with a certain element).

```
pairMap[f_, s_] := Module[{ss = s}, 
  Flatten[Outer[f, {#}, ss = Rest@ss, 1] & /@ Most@s, 2] ]

pairMap[f, Range@5000] // Length // Timing

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> {7.816, 38376}
>
> 19430512

This also uses only a small amount of memory, and testing should bear out that it is faster as well.  A variation of this method that may be even faster is to not build an output expression at all, relying instead on `Sow` and `Reap` to gather your results:

```
g[a_, b_] /; b ~Divisible~ a := Sow[ {a, b} ]

pairScan[f_, s_] := Module[{ss = s}, Outer[f, {#}, ss = Rest@ss, 1] & ~Scan~ Most@s ]

Reap[ pairScan[g, Range@5000] ][[2, 1]] // Length // Timing

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> {6.583, 38376}
>
> 18757552

#### An argument for `Do` loops

While `Outer` is somewhat faster, after further consideration and conferring with [jVincent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1194/jvincent) I think perhaps after all a `Do` loop is as good as anything.  One could write `pairScan` in this way:

```
pairScan2[f_, s_] := Module[{ss = s}, Do[f[i, j], {i, ss}, {j, ss = Rest@ss}] ]

Reap[ pairScan2[g, Range@5000] ][[2, 1]] // Length // Timing

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> {7.613, 38376}
>
> 18711080

Comment: Very helpful, I can solve my problem and learned a lot at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

```
vertices = Range[10];
pairs = Tuples[vertices, 2];
func[x__] := First@x <= Last@x;
edges = Pick[pairs, func[#] & /@ pairs];
(* or *)
edges = Pick[pairs, Boole[func[#]] & /@ pairs, 1];
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

```
 Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexLabels -> "Name",  ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

```
vertices = Range[100];
pairs = Tuples[vertices, 2];
func2[x__] := PrimeQ[(First@x)^(Last@x) + 3];
edges = Pick[pairs, func2[#] & /@ pairs];
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ edges, ImagePadding -> 20,
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexLabelStyle -> Red,
  VertexStyle -> White,
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Point",
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Hue[.15, .5, .8]],
  Background -> Black,
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[.01], Arrow[#1, 0.01]} &), 
  ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

**Update: Using `SparseArray` with `AdjacencyGraph` and `Graph`:**

```
func2[x__] := PrimeQ[(First@x)^(Last@x) + 3]; (* or your choice of test function *)
adjmtrx = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; func2[{i, j}] -> 1}, {20, 20}];
styling = {ImagePadding -> 20,
     VertexLabels -> "Name",
     VertexLabelStyle -> Red,
     VertexStyle -> White,
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Point",
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Hue[.15, .5, .8]],
     Background -> Black,
     EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[.02], Arrow[#1, 0.01]} &), 
     ImageSize -> 400};

Row[{AdjacencyGraph[adjmtrx, styling], Spacer[5], 
      Graph[Range@First@Dimensions[adjmtrx], 
           DirectedEdge @@@ adjmtrx["NonzeroPositions"], styling]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are definitely shorter, non-loop ways to do this. Define your link-defining function like this (with whatever test you need as the first argument to `If`:

```
islinked[a_Integer?Positive, b_Integer?Positive] := 
 If[Mod[a, 3] == 0 && Mod[b, 2] == 1, a -> b, {}]
```

You can then `Apply` this at the level of each row using the `@@@` shorthand.
I would use `Tuples` rather than `Subsets` to allow for both `1->2` and `2->1`.
Eliminate the empty cases with a replacement rule as shown.

```
gg = islinked @@@ Tuples[Range[10], 2] /. {} -> Sequence[]

(* {3 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 7, 3 -> 9, 6 -> 1, 6 -> 3, 6 -> 5, 
    6 -> 7, 6 -> 9, 9 -> 1, 9 -> 3, 9 -> 5, 9 -> 7, 9 -> 9} *)

Graph[gg]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this and the next answer. One question though, and it cuts to the center of my post: does generating the list of subsets (or tuples) beforehand cause a difficulty? If the original list has n elements, there are n(n-1) pairs. Maybe mathematica knows to generate them iteratively, as it is handling the Apply?

Comment: @michar - I find `Tuples` to be pretty quick: but note, it has n*n pairs - things like 2 -> 2 are possible, thus the self-loops in the picture above.