# Levels: how do they work?

Tags: list-manipulation

I cannot understand how Mathematica manages levels, and so it's always a painful try-and-fail to use `Flatten`. Can someone please give me a very clear definition?

If you feel like giving an example, please tell me how to turn this list

`{{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}, ...}`

into

`{{a, a1}, {b, b1}, {c, c1}, ...}`

with `Flatten`, if possible.

Comment: I discussed levels briefly on my book, [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node79.html) - this might be helpful.

Comment: well, there are lots of questions on stack exchange whose answer is a sort of handbook/definition. Since I couldn't find anything on the Internet, this could be very well a place to put something clear. About the example, I see that it's not possible to do with a simple argument to `Flatten`, like `n` or `{n}`

Comment: @Lorenzo, there are also two versions `Map[Apply[Sequence], list, {2}]` and `Map[Apply[Sequence], list, {-2}]`; you may use `Trace` to see how it works.

Comment: The link given by @LeonidShifrin does not work. See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507000317/http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node79.html).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is by no means a complete analysis of levels. (See [Leonid's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node79.html) for a more thorough presentation.)

You can visualize levels with TreeForm:

```
x = F[G[a, K[d]], H[b, L[e]], J[c, M[P[f, g]]]];
TreeForm[x]
```

I avoided nested lists for clarity; also, because the output of `Level` is itself put into a list.

[image: treeform]

One must resist the temptation to think of levels as the vertical height of vertices on a TreeForm display.  A single `Level` will often cut a vertical swath out of the TreeForm, as the following shows.

**Positive Levels**

Here's a diagram of levels corresponding to non-negative integers. 
When the parameter in braces is positive, the results will always begin at the same depth in the tree; however, the end depth (where a leaf terminates a branch) depends on the depth of the branch, not the (greatest) depth of the tree.

Notice that level 0 contains the head, `F` as well as all of the arguments inside it.  Level 5 contains nothing; there is no level 5.

```
Grid@Table[{"level ", k, "  ", Level[x, {k}], "\n"}, {k, 0, 5}]
```

[image: positive levels]

[image: positive 2]

---

**Negative Levels**

Here counting begins from the bottom of the tree. The "bottom" lies at various depths, as the following example shows.  Level -1 holds the leaves of the tree.

```
Grid@Table[{"level ", k, "  ", Level[x, {-k}], "\n"}, {k, 1, 5}]
```

[image: minus]

[image: Neg 2]

Raul Nahrain suggested drawing the tree itself "from the bottom of the pane to the top".
Mathematica will not display TreeForm this way; you'll need to hand edit it.
But what you get is clearer, provided that you realize that we are using a non-standard display of `TreeForm`.

[image]

Comment: Great visuals! Like it.

Comment: Great answer, David! Big +1.

Answer (score 29):

As an alternative, I always felt that replacement rules were quite clear in what they are doing.  For your problem:

```
{{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}} /. {a_, {a1_}} -> {a, a1}
```

Comment: very interesting.

Answer (score 29):

David Carraher's answer is quite nice, but I think to really make sense of negative levels you have to draw the tree in a slightly different way, starting from the leaves upwards.

[image]

To be clear, the $i$th level consists not just of the *heads* here (*e.g.* `K`, `L`, and `P` at level -2) but of the entire subexpressions that they are the heads of (`K[d]`, `L[e]`, and `P[f,g]`).

Comment: @David: Well, I haven't mentioned how to interpret the diagram yet. :) It's safe to say that level $i$ consists of all the *subtrees* which are *rooted* at the heads labeled $i$ in this diagram, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, how can I construct such pics? :)))

Answer (score 28):

```
Flatten/@list1
```

> {{a, a1}, {b, b1}, {c, c1}}

Will also work by flattening each element of your list at the top level.

Answer (score 22):

For situations simular to those illustrated in your example, I wouldn't use `Flatten`. Rather, I would use `Position` and `FlattenAt`. This pair of functions will not only handle your example but also much more complicated ones. It is easy to use because `Position` finds the right level expresion for you.

Let's look at two examples:

```
example1 = {{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}};

Position[example1, {_}]

(* ==>{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}} *)
```

Now we know where to apply `FlattenAt`

```
FlattenAt[example1, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]

(* ==> {{a, a1}, {b, b1}, {c, c1}} *)
```

Of course, in everyday situations, we would compose `Position` and `FlattenAt`:

```
example2 = {{a, {a1, a2}}, {b, {b1, b2}}, {c, {c1, c2}}};
FlattenAt[example2, Position[example2, {_, _}]]

(* ==>{a, a1, a2, b, b1, b2, c, c1, c2} *)
```

Comment: +1. The documentation does not connect `Position` and `FlattenAt` at all. And the documentation page for `FlattenAt` is very scanty.

Answer (score 12):

The most straight forward way I can think of at the moment is to use `Flatten` together with `Partition.`

```
list1 = {{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}};
```

First remove all inner braces with `Flatten`

```
Flatten@list1
```

gives you

```
 {a, a1, b, b1, c, c1}
```

and now you can rearrange the list in any way you want using `Partition`

```
Partition[Flatten@list1, 2]
```

which yields:

```
{{a, a1}, {b, b1}, {c, c1}}
```

Answer (score 8):

To me, the easiest way of thinking about (positive) levels is to ask the question "how many indices are required to specify the location of an object?".

For example, two indices are required to specify the elements in a matrix. For the following two examples,

```
example1 = {{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}};
example2 = {{a, {a1, a2}}, {b, {b1, b2}}, {c, {c1, c2}}};
```

three indices are required to specify the (positive) location of a1.

```
example1[[1,2,1]]
```

> a1

Map acts at a specified level and Apply replaces the head at a specified level. One trick to working out what function to apply at which level is to use an arbitrary function, e.g.

```
Map[g,example1]
```

> ```
> {g[{a, {a1}}], g[{b, {b1}}], g[{c, {c1}}]}
> ```

```
Apply[g,example2,{2}]
```

> ```
> {{a, g[a1, a2]}, {b, g[b1, b2]}, {c, g[c1, c2]}}
> ```

to see where the function will be applied, and what it needs to do.

So, for these examples, with uniform structure, we can use Map and Flatten or Apply and Sequence:

```
Flatten /@ example1
```

> ```
> {{a, a1}, {b, b1}, {c, c1}}
> ```

```
Apply[Sequence,example2,{2}]
```

> ```
> {{a, a1, a2}, {b, b1, b2}, {c, c1, c2}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Excellent discussion and great explanations.

The following will retrieve all expressions of a list at all levels sorting by Position. Might help when looking to extract specific elements from an expression.  Useful with ragged lists.

So if

```
x = F[G[a, K[d]], H[b, L[e]], J[c, M[P[f, g]]]]
```

`rfli[x]` will be:

```
rfli[list_] := (coltitles = {"Expression", "Position"}; 
     Grid[
          Prepend[
               SortBy[
                    Union[
                         MapThread[List, {Level[list, {0, Depth[list]}],
                              Map[Position[list, #] &, Level[list, {0, Depth[list]}]]}
                         ]
                    ],
               Last],
          coltitles],
     Frame -> All, Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9],
          {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}},
     Alignment -> {Left}]);
```

[image: grid table]

Further, for the same list x we find that
[image: Positive/negative levels for elements within a list.]

If interested I can post more code.

Comment: That's good; +1. Please, in the future format your code accordingly. You can consult the help centre or the `?` mark on the right when answering/asking a question. And welcome :D !

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

```
list = {{a, {a1}}, {b, {b1}}, {c, {c1}}};
{#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2, 1]]} &@list // Transpose
Map[{#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} &, list]
```

Comment: ...two alternatives?

Comment: Er, my English is poor.