# What do brackets around a levelspec option do?

Tags: documentation

The following code returns the first three integer elements of `Sqrt[Range[100]]`:

```
Cases[Sqrt[Range[100]], _Integer, 2, 3]
{1, 2, 3}
```

The following code looks like the preceding code but returns a different result:

```
Cases[Sqrt[Range[100]], _Integer, {2}, 3]
{2, 3, 5}
```

As we can see in the following picture, the argument `{2}` is not documented (it has no braces in the documentation):

[image]

What does the second code with `{2}` instead of `2` mean?

Comment: see documentation carefully it is there.

Comment: This is *buried* in the documentation.  I had this same question about Level[] and wouldn't have known to look in the Cases[] documentation.  I only found this page with community help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually this *is* [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html); you need to look under **More Information** or **Details and Options**:

[image]

Further, you should realize that *levelspec* has special meaning in that is it describes a format that is common to a number of functions.  *Levelspec* is described in:

- Tutorial [Some General Notations and Conventions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html#30382)
- Tutorial [Levels in Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html)
- Documentation for [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html)

See also: [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121)

Comment: Why is this question different and wasn't closed already? :)

Comment: @Kuba different from what?

Comment: From others which answer is in *Details and Options*. Obviously (upvotes) this answer is helpful for community but isn't it an example of question which shoud be closed in order to keep repository transparent? Well, I know "should" is not a good word, if there are votes to close it will be. Maybe I should ask: "isn't the policy of SE to close such questions?"

Comment: @Kuba I don't understand "keep repository transparent."  As far as "SE policy" there is none for such a case; we have added **simple mistake** / **easily found** as a custom close reason, but that does not IMHO mean that *all* questions which are answered by the documentation need to be closed.  The documentation isn't always easy to navigate and I hope that this answer serves to group information relating to *levelspec* in a useful fashion.

Comment: I agree than not *all* need to be closed, but  in this case, the answer is almost on top. I do not demand anything, I have also not reason to doubt in your intentions, I just wanted to ask to avoid working against community by voting to close. By *"keep repository transparent."* I meant, we can rewrite documentation here be such database would be not handy. It is also due to search engine but it is a long story... :) ("Levels: how do...", shoud be easily found by typing "levels" etc. but it isn't due to ":" in the title, check `title:levels: is:question` and `title:levels is:question`)