# How to apply function f for each time value t, to each pixel from image, resulting in t images

Tags: functions, image-processing, list-manipulation, map

I have a 2D array of complex values and I want to apply a function to every entry of the array, for every timepoint t in a list. I know how to apply my function to one entry for every time t in a list, and I know how to apply my function for one t to every entry in an array. (I keep finding answers to those problems when searching with google and on SE) Somehow I cant get both to work at the same tim, and I cant find an explanation of how to do it either. Maybe someone has experience in doing this?

Example:

```
In:
function[source_, t_] := source(1+Sin[2Pi*t]);
lena = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
size = ImageDimensions[lena];
data = ImageData[lena];
times = Table[i, {i, 600}]/10;
complexred = Fourier[data[[1;;size[[2]],1;;size[[1]],1]]];
newdata = function[complexred, times];

Out:
Thread::tdlen : Objects of unequal length in 
{{...some complex values here...}{<<1>>},<<48>>,<<430>>} cannot be combined.
```

Thanks!

Comment: `f(x)` means `f*x`. Compare `ImageDimensions[lena]` and `Dimensions[data]`

Comment: Ah those brackets were a typo, sorry. Matlab automatisms :). Thank you for pointing out the difference in coordinates for images and matrices! Thats useful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
fn[img_Image][t_] := ImageApply[Evaluate[# (1 + Sin[2 Pi*t])] &, img]

times = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];

fn[lena] /@ times
```

[image]

I used [SubValues notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121) for flexibility (direct mapping onto `times`) but it is not required.  You can also use the function like this:

```
Table[fn[lena][i], {i, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

I pre-evaluated the body of the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) for best speed, but this is also not required.  (Note that `Evaluate` must be applied to the entire body of a `Function` for it to have the desired effect; to evaluate a piece of the body use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html).)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and explaining how an why you perform each step. Nice and illustrative. I take it the `/@` operator can be applied to arrays of complex numbers as well, as thats what bill s does. I dont quite understand the `#*body &, img` part yet. What do the `#` and `&` do there?

Comment: @Leo You're welcome.  Let me know if you have any other questions about what I wrote.  Yes, `/@` which is short for `Map` can be applied to any expression, with control over level using the full notation `Map[func, expr, levelspec]`.  Bookmark [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for reference.  You can also select an operator such as `/@`, `#` or `&` in the Front End and press F1 to bring up the help page for it. (continued)

Comment: `#` is short for `Slot`, and `&` is short for `Function`; they are the basic building blocks of anonymous functions in *Mathematica*.  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29752/121) and linked resources for an explanation of *levelspec*.

Comment: Both links are very useful, thanks.

Comment: @Leo I changed my `With` construct to `Evaluate`, which in this particular case is less baroque.  Be careful to understand how `Evaluate` works before attempting to apply it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You say that your data has the form of complex values, so I will make up some complex-valued data and a range of time:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}] + I RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];
time = Range[0, 1, 0.05];
```

Now consider a function

```
f[x_, t_] := Abs[x]^t
```

The goal is to "apply the function to every element of the data, for every timepoint." One way to do this is:

```
g = f[data, #] & /@ time
```

which gives an array of size

```
Dimensions[g]
{21, 10, 10}
```

This makes sense since there are 21 points in the time list and the data is a 10x10 array.

Comment: Thanks you for answering my question! Although strictly your answer more directly answers my question than mr.wizards (by using complex numbers and explaining the resulting array), I did accept his answer because both your answers are actually the same method and his answer also showed me some extra tricks for using `/@` effectively. But I like your explanation about the dimensions of the resulting array, since that was in my question as well. So thanks.