# Determine if a variable appears in an expression or not?

Tags: searching

Consider an arbitrary expression `expr`. This expression may contain arbitrary data, like integers, variables, implicit functions etc. Now, I would like to determine if the variable `a` does or does not appear in `expr` (which means, `a` could be a factor, or a subscript, or a power, or a function argument, does not matter). If `a` appears - give back `True` or `1`, if `a` does not appear, give back `False` or `0`. Is there such a function in Mathematica? Or maybe one can implement it? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What result would you like for `expr = Integrate[f[a],{a,1,3}]`? If `True`, then `MemberQ` is your function. If `False` (because `a` is a dummy variable, or scoped, if you prefer), then could use ``Internal`DependsOnQ[expr,a]``.

Comment: @Daniel Could you tell us a little more about `DependsOnQ`?  Perhaps post an answer?  By the way don't forget to use double back-ticks to offset code that itself contains a back-tick. (FIFY)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The functions you are looking for are [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) and [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html).
- Both functions take a [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121) and the Option [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html), but the default value for each is different.

You can determine if expression `x` appears anywhere in `a` using:

```
MemberQ[a, x, {0, -1}, Heads -> True]
```

Or assuming the default option `Heads -> True` for `FreeQ` simply:

```
! FreeQ[a, x]
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, after I posted the question, I thought of a trivial solution myself. In case if someone else will have a similar question, here it is:

```
FindVar[expr_, var_] := Module[{temp},
temp = Hold[expr] /. var -> 0;
If[temp === Hold[expr], False, True]
]
```

Comment: +1 for a rather clever attack of such a problem. :-)

Comment: I confess I don't understand Mathematica syntax enough for this, but my untrained reading of it leads me to think it would say that `x` is not present in `x-x`. Is that a concern? Or are expressions like `x-x` and `exp(x)/exp(x)` not of concern?

Comment: @alex.jordan I think you have a valid concern.  However `x - x` *already* evaluates to `0` so if the `expr` is not held `x` *does not* appear inside it, if you see what I mean.  Other cases may be more complex, however wrapping `expr` in `Hold` should fix most problems I believe.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do understand, I just don't know if there are expressions that simplify a lot, possibly losing `x`, but are so complicated that Mathematica doesn't simplify them as much as actually possible. Still not knowing much yet about Mathematica, but if I understand what your answer is doing, it is looking at the parse tree of the expression, which seems like the real deal. There's also a whole separate issue of what would happen if you used `FindVar[1/(x-1),x]` and the expression is just not defined at `x -> 1`.

Comment: You need not to replace var by a number. It is sufficient and more reliable to replace it with another variable or any other expression and then compare it with the original using ===. This technique become completely safe if you wrap the expression by Hold beforehand.

Comment: I adjusted the above answer to what Alexey Popkov suggested.

Answer (score 4):

[Posting as response per request.]

If the goal is to determine a "functional" dependency then the undocumented `` Internal`DependsOnQ `` might be a better choice. This function will weed out for example usage within dummy variables in definite `Integrate`. The indefinite case really should, and does, give dependence. Here is a quick example.

```
expri = Integrate[f[a], a];
exprd = Integrate[f[a], {a, 1, 3}];

In[230]:= Map[Internal`DependsOnQ[#, a] &, {expri, exprd}]

(* Out[230]= {True, False} *)
```

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work: like ``Internal`DependsOnQ[Limit[f[x], x -> 3], x]`` gives `True` when the answer should be `False`.  I have a feeling that ``Internal`DependsOnQ`` relies on a preprogramed database of symbols which it checks, and `Limit` was left out by accident.

Comment: @QuantumDot I'll see what I can find out about that example. Might be an issue along the lines you suggest.

Comment: Hi @DanielLichtblau, any word on the issue of `Limit` with ``Internal`DependsOnQ``?

Comment: @QuantumDot Still an issue, I'm afraid.