# Cannot use Part in Pure Function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, syntax

I need to select some lists in the nested list of form of {{1,2,3},{2,3,4}}.
I have used Select to complete my work. But when I tried Position, it doesn't work.
For example,

```
 Flatten@@Position[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, _?(# == {1, 2, 3} &)]
```

gives me the correct answer of $\{1\}$,but when I use

```
Flatten@@Position[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, _?(#[[1;;2]] == {1, 2} &)]
```

returns the error

> Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 2 in List. >>
>   Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 2 in List. >>
>   Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 3 in 1 >>

It seems that it is not working with lists, and it is also trying to apply to higher level.
Why is it and how to fix that?

Comment: I did not realize this was a duplicate until after I answered.  I am converting my answer to Community Wiki so that I do not gain additional "reputation" from it, and so that others can add anything that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Position` by default looks at all parts of the expression, including those that do not have sub-parts to extract.  You can use [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121) and the Option [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) to restrict what it tests:

```
Position[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, _?(#[[1 ;; 2]] == {1, 2} &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {{1}}
> ```

More generally you can simply use a pattern like this:

```
Position[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, _[1, 2, ___]]
```

> ```
> {{1}}
> ```

This pattern matches all heads:

```
Position[{foo[1, 2, 3], bar[2, 3, 4]}, _[1, 2, ___]]
```

> ```
> {{1}}
> ```