# Levels and slots

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, functional-style

I am struggling with levels and `#`, if I understand this I think I will be able to grasp the entire concept.

```
 Apply[#1 &, {envelope[1, order["sku1", 5, 10, 4.98]], 
  envelope[2, order["sku2", 3, 67, 98]]}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {1,2}
> ```

This makes perfect sense.

Keeping everything els equal but changing the slot to `#2`:

> ```
> {order["sku1", 5, 10, 4.98], order["sku2", 3, 67, 98]}
> ```

This makes also perfect scence.

Then I am going back to `#1` but now at level `2`

> ```
> {envelope[1, "sku1"], envelope[2, "sku2"]}
> ```

Why do I get this output I was only expecting `Sku1` and `Sku2`.

I also wonder why Depth in this case equals 4, but if I put level 3 I get the entire list?

I know this is very simple but I have been struggling with seeing the logic.

I have spent quite a lot of time trying to grasp this so please try make it as clear as possible. And If you do not understand the question or think it is  poorly explained give me a comment before downgrading the question.

Comment: Duplicate of ["Levels: How do they work?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/5)

Comment: @rm-rf I think it is closely related. Although convolved, OP's problem seems to more about `Apply` than the `Levels` which is well answered by Murta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to understand using `Map`. Using:

```
list ={envelope[1,order["sku1",5,10,4.98]],envelope[2,order["sku2",3,67,98]]}
```

if you do `Map[f,list,{2}]`, you get:

```
{envelope[f[1],f[order[sku1,5,10,4.98]]],envelope[f[2],f[order[sku2,3,67,98]]]}
```

The trick here is that `Apply` when used in an Atom is the Atom itself.

```
f @@ 1
```

> 1

So with `Apply[# &, list, {2}]` you get:

```
{envelope[1,sku1],envelope[2,sku2]}
```

Levels are nicely visualized using `TreeForm`:

[image]

[This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/levels-how-do-they-work) has a much more deeper and illustrative Level explanation.

Comment: Murta you talked about Atom, what does that actually mean? I understand Map, but Apply I do not.

Comment: @ALEXANDER [ref/AtomQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html), [guide/Atomic Elements of Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/AtomicElementsOfExpressions.html)