# Where can I find mathematica documentation about @@@?

Tags: pattern-matching

For example, to build a rule from 2 lists `{a,b,c}`, `{1,2,3}`, I use:

```
Rule @@@ Transpose[{{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}

OK, but how `@@@` works ? (Black magic for me)

I am using Mathemtica 7.0.

Comment: Look here -- [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

Comment: Duplicate; please see specifically this answer: [(25616)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121)

Comment: Also... if you write `@@@` to documentation centre (at least on recent versions of Mma), it does list `Apply` for you.

Comment: Recommended reading: [(15567)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121), [(46238)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121)