# Mapping on leaves

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Say I have some nested structure, such as `{a,{{b,c},d,{e,{f,g}}}}`, and I want to apply a function $q$ to each of the leaves; that is, I want the output to be `{q[a],{{q[b],q[c]},q[d],{q[e],{q[f],q[g]}}}}`. There must be a primitive to do this, but I can't find it. I initially thought that `Map` with a third argument of `Infinity` would do it, but that does something different (in addition to applying `q` at the leaves, it also applies it to each higher-level list element).

Comment: `Attributes[q] = Listable` or you can `Map` at  `{-1}` unless `a,b,c...` are non atomic,

Comment: @Kuba I guess I should have read that page more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba I should note that the `Attributes[q] = Listable` version won't work unless all containers for leaves are `List`s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little "secret" of level specifications is that they can be negative.  `-1` refers to the atomic leaves, `-2` refers to all [`Depth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Depth.html) 2 subexpressions, generally `-k` refers to all depth `k` subexpressions.  Thus the behaviour of negative levels is somewhat different from that of positive ones.

You can read more here:

- [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/12)
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html

Mapping at level `{-1}` (i.e. only level `-1`, not a range of levels) will accomplish what you need.

```
Level[{a, {{b, c}, d, {e, {f, g}}}}, {-1}]
(* {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} *)

Map[x, {a, {{b, c}, d, {e, {f, g}}}}, {-1}]
(* {x[a], {{x[b], x[c]}, x[d], {x[e], {x[f], x[g]}}}} *)
```

Comment: This reminds me of Bob Ross [badly paraphrased]: "...just happy little secrets..."

Comment: Worth linking: [Levels: how do they work?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks!  I knew there had to be such a post, but couldn't find the right one.  I wasn't familiar with this specific question you linked, but it seems to be the best one.