# Position with test for list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Why do I get this error message? It seems to me that the level specification should have done the job.

```
In[1]:= RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}]
In[2]:= Position[%, _?(#[[1]] > 5 &), {1}] 

Out[1]:= {{0, 0}, {1, 7}, {3, 0}, {5, 5}, {1, 5}, {10, 6}, {3, 9}, \
{0, 1}, {9, 1}, {2, 0}}
```

> During evaluation of In[2]:= Part::partd: Part specification List[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

```
Out[2]:= {{6}, {9}}
```

Comment: `Position[list, _, {-2}] ` and `Position[list, _, {1}] ` are different

Comment: @garej why different?

Comment: you may find this [famous post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15577/24604) useful.

Comment: Also this form works `Position[%, _?(And[Depth[#] > 1, #[[1]] > 5] &), {1}]`

Comment: @garej I think you will find interest in my answer to the original question now linked at the top.  You do not need `Depth` etc., but only `Position[%, _[__]?(#[[1]] > 5 &), {1}]`.  If one is willing to modify the test function itself this can be written more cleanly as `Position[%, _[x_, ___] /; x > 5, {1}]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the `Depth` of your knowledge of MMA and SE is outstanding.   I was trying to address the issue too literally, as a result, at the cost of clarity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation for Position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) provides the answer:

> The default level specification for Position is {0,Infinity}, with Heads->True.

You're not setting Heads -> False, so Position will look at:

```
Level[{{8, 7}, {10, 8}, {6, 10}, {3, 2}, {9, 8}, {0, 1}, {2, 1},
{1, 10}, {6, 8}, {5, 9}}, 1, Heads -> True]
```

Which is:

> {List, {8, 7}, {10, 8}, {6, 10}, {3, 2}, {9, 8}, {0, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 
>     10}, {6, 8}, {5, 9}}

You're then asking Position to take `#[[1]]`, i.e. `List[[1]]`... Error!

This works:

```
RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}]
Position[%, _?(#[[1]] > 5 &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two more lines from [Position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) documentation might be relevant for the OP.

> A positive level `n` consists of all parts of *expr* specified by `n` indices.
>
> A negative level `-n` consists of all parts of *expr* with depth `n`.

So, for the OP task this code works even with default `Heads->True`:

```
list = RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}];

Position[list, _?(#[[1]] > 5 &), {-2}]
```

---

To see why it happens let's make a toy list, `ls = {{a,b},{c,d}}`.

```
Position[ls, _, {1}]
(*  {{0}, {1}, {2}}  *)
```

We may see, that all positions have *one* index inside `{}`. Heads included (they have `0` as one of indeces).

```
Position[ls, _, {2}]
(*  {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}  *)
```

We may see, that all positions have *two* indeces inside `{}`. Heads included.

---

On the contrary, negative *levelspecs* work in a different way in `Position`:

```
 Position[ls, _, {-2}]
 (* {{1}, {2}} *)
```

These are positions of elements with `Depth[..]==2`; let's check this:

```
 MapAt[Depth[#] &, ls, Position[ls, _, {-2}]]
 (*  {2, 2} *)
```

As a footnote, this statement gives different result (note the head `1`):

```
 MapAt[Depth[#] &, ls, Position[ls, _, {1}]]
 (*  1[2,2] *)
```

Finally,

```
 Position[ls, _, {-1}]
 (* {{0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

These are positions of elements with `Depth[..]==1`; let's check:

```
MapAt[Depth[#] &, ls, Position[ls, _, {-1}]]
(* 1[1[1, 1], 1[1, 1]] *)
```

We may see all `1` (including `Heads`).

---

One has to be careful with more complex cases of nested lists.