# Extract all elements from a list that belong to a set or have a set element as an argument

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation

EDIT: Added that I want to extract not only the variables from a specific set, but also functions involving variables from a specific set.

Given the set

```
S = [s1, s2, s3]
```

and some vector of values

```
x = {1, 2, 4, s1, y, f1[s1], f2[s2]}
```

I want to pick out all values in `x` that belong to the set `S`, and also all functions involving arguments with from the set `S`. Maybe some approach like

```
Smash[x_] := Cases[{x}, _, {0, Infinity}] (*Eq. Smash[f1[s1]] = {f1[s1],s1})
Select[x, IntersectingQ[Smash[#], S] ]
```

But it really doesn't work. I guess it's an issue regarding the syntax mainly, I don't really know what do with `#`. How can I solve this? Any answers explaining the syntax issue or giving alternative solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (i) you should change square brackets in assignment of S (ii) avoid capital letters to avoid conflicts with MMA built-ins (iii)why not use `Intersection[S,x]`.(iv) to make you own code work just put an & at the end of your criterion

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange Martin.  I attempted to address your needs in an answer below.  Nevertheless this question will probably be closed as "easily found in the documentation."  I know the documentation can be opaque at times.  Consider possibly also making use of these resources: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/ and [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121) as well as the links in the **Introduction** section of [(18)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121).

Comment: ubpdqn: Thy! Just tried

 Select[x, IntersectingQ[Smash[#], S] &] but it gives me

Tag Slot in #1 is Protected.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 7):

What I think you want:

```
S = {s1, s2, s3};

x = {1, 2, 4, s1, y};

Intersection[x, S]
```

Outputs: `{s1}`

As for `#` see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html

---

For your edited question:

```
set = {s1, s2, s3};
x = {1, 2, 4, s1, y, f1[s1], f2[s2]}

p = Alternatives @@ set;

Cases[x, p | _[p]]
```

> ```
> {s1, f1[s1], f2[s2]}
> ```

Reference [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html).

---

Addressing your most recent comment I think you want:

```
set = {s1, s2, s3};
x = {1, 2, f1[s1 + s2] , f2[f1[s1] + s3], 4, f3[s1 + q], s1, y, f1[s1], f2[s2]}

p = Alternatives @@ set;

Select[x, Not@*FreeQ[p]]
```

> ```
> {f1[s1 + s2], f2[s3 + f1[s1]], f3[q + s1], s1, f1[s1], f2[s2]}
> ```

Reference [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) and [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

If however you wish to exclude `f3[q + s1]` because of `q` you will need to look at the leaves of the expression, but not heads:

```
Select[x, FreeQ[#, Except[p], {-1}, Heads -> False] &]
```

> ```
> {f1[s1 + s2], f2[s3 + f1[s1]], s1, f1[s1], f2[s2]}
> ```

Reference: [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121)

Comment: did you think my comment was terse or discourteous? I did not mean it that way.

Comment: @ubpdqn Are you asking me that because I also posted a comment?  I was writing it before yours appeared.  I see no problem with your comment.  In fact you mentioned that user symbols starting with Capital Letters is a bad idea, which is something I forgot.

Comment: No it was a great answer! However, I just realised that the question is a bit more extensive than I first thought. I updated the original post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I felt guilty for not sating welcome or putting a format welcome message. I just thought it could be resolved quickly.

Comment: Neat, really neat! Tried to upvote your answer but I don't have reputation enough to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Next challenge is that I want to extract a function containing any expression related to the set, for instance f1[s1+s2] or f2[f1[s1]+s3].

Really got stuck here. Guess some recursion could solve it. Hmm.

Answer (score 7):

It is not completely clear to me what form the output is intended to take. Recommend that you always give examples of both inputs and corresponding outputs.

```
S = {s1, s2, s3};

x = {1, 2, 4, s1, y, f1[s1], f2[s2], f1[s1 + s2], f2[f1[s1] + s3]};

DeleteCases[x, _?(FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ S] &)]

(*  {s1, f1[s1], f2[s2], f1[s1 + s2], f2[s3 + f1[s1]]}  *)
```