# Higher functional programming partial substitution

Tags: plotting

This

```
h[g_, x_] := g[x]
h[Sqrt, x^2]
```

works obviously as well as :

```
f[x_]:= x^2
h[f,x]
```

but if

```
 k[x_] := Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]   

 h[k,x]
```

works but

```
 h[k, x^2]
```

since the substitution of $x^2$ is done also in the range. Is there a way to manage the substitution only partialy

Comment: I wonder, how is *Mathematica* to know here that what you want is the `x` for the range, rather than, say, the `2` or the `Power`? How is it implemented in other languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you in most cases:

```
kk[x_] :=
 With[{var = FirstCase[x, _Symbol, x, {-1}, Heads -> False]},
   Plot[x, {var, 0, 1}]
 ]

h[kk, 3 + x^2]
```

[image]

#### Notes:

- `Heads -> False` is the default for [`FirstCase`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstCase.html) but it is more robust to include the option explicitly.
- One might also use `First @ Variables[x]` in place of the `FirstCase` expression but there might be cases where `FirstCase` works better.  While inadvisable this is valid input:

  ```
    Plot[2 Pi, {Pi, 0, 5}]
  ```

  yet `First @ Variables[2 Pi]` will throw an error message because `Variables` does not see `Pi` as a variable, but `h[kk, 2 Pi]` will still work with the code as written above.

Comment: I do not underestand why in FirstCase[x, _Symbol, x, {-1}, Heads -> False] there is a second x and {-1}, But obviously, it works.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki The third parameter is the default if no match is found, so I just used the given `x` expression in the event that `FirstCase` cannot find a `_Symbol`.  `{-1}` is a *levelspec* -- please see [(15567)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121) for a better understanding.