# Creating a third list from two given lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I imported 2 lists of the form `{{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...}` and `{{x1,y'1}, {x2,y'2}, ...}` into Mathematica. I want to make a  `ListPlot` the list `{{x1, y1 - y'1}, {x2, y2 - y'2}, ...}`.

How can I create the third list by subtracting only the second column values of the first two lists keeping the first column intact.

Comment: Something like `MapThread[(({Mean[#1], Subtract @@ #2} &) @@ Transpose[##]) &, {list1, list2}]`, I guess. (I'm not at a computer to check.)

Comment: `p={{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}; q={{x1,Y1},{x2,Y2}};f[r_,s_]:={r[[1]],r[[2]]-s[[2]]};
MapThread[f,{p,q}]`

Comment: look up [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is:

```
p = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}; q = {{x1, Y1}, {x2, Y2}};
p - ({0, 1} # & /@ q)
(* {{x1, y1 - Y1}, {x2, y2 - Y2}} *)
```

This works by simply replacing the first column of one of the lists with `0` before subtracting.

Answer (score 3):

Lists in *Mathematica* can be picked apart with `Part`.

If you evaluate [`Dimensions[list1]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) the output should be something like `{n,2}` where `n` is an integer equal to the number of pairs in your list (check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/levels-how-do-they-work) on the levels of expressions in *Mathematica*).

Alternatively, you can think `list1` as a [matrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixAndTensorOperations.html) (see "*Structural Operations*" section) with `n` rows and 2 columns. The same stands true for `list2`.

In order to "*...keep the first column*" from either list you can use `Part`;

```
x = Part[list1, All, 1]
```

After evaluating the previous line, `x` now is a `List` with the x-coordinates of `list1`.

In order to "*...subtract the second columns*", you'll first need to obtain them as lists (also, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns) for in-place manipulation).

Using again `Part` in a similar fashion as before will yield `y1` and `y2` ie the y-coordinates of lists 1 and 2. The difference this time is that we need to take the *second* entry from *every* row (that's what `All` stands for).

After having obtained the `y1` and `y2` subtracting one from the other and combining them into an output list is straightforward:

```
Transpose[{x,y1-y2}]
```

Comment: Or all on one line: `Thread@{list1[[All, 1]], list1[[All, 2]] - list2[[All, 2]]}`

Comment: Or `Transpose[{list1[[;; , 1]], list1[[;; , 2]] - list2[[;; , 2]]}]`

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association). Here is a small example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
d1 = Thread[{Range[10], RandomReal[1, 10]}]
d2 = Thread[{Range[10], RandomReal[1, 10]}]
```

> {{1, 0.817389}, {2, 0.11142}, {3, 0.789526}, {4, 0.187803}, {5, 0.241361}, {6,
>      0.0657388}, {7, 0.542247}, {8, 0.231155}, {9, 0.396006}, {10, 0.700474}}
>
> {{1, 0.211826}, {2, 0.748657}, {3, 0.422851}, {4, 0.247495}, {5, 
>     0.977172}, {6, 0.825163}, {7, 0.925275}, {8, 0.578056}, {9, 0.29287}, {10, 
>     0.208051}}

Convert to an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) object:

```
a1 = AssociationThread @@ Transpose @ d1
a2 = AssociationThread @@ Transpose @ d2
```

> <|1 -> 0.817389, 2 -> 0.11142, 3 -> 0.789526, 4 -> 0.187803, 5 -> 0.241361, 
>    6 -> 0.0657388, 7 -> 0.542247, 8 -> 0.231155, 9 -> 0.396006, 10 -> 0.700474|>
>
> <|1 -> 0.211826, 2 -> 0.748657, 3 -> 0.422851, 4 -> 0.247495, 5 -> 0.977172, 
>    6 -> 0.825163, 7 -> 0.925275, 8 -> 0.578056, 9 -> 0.29287, 10 -> 0.208051|>

Now, when we subtract 2 [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) objects, we get a new [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) object where the values are the differences between the values of each individual [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association). So:

```
r = a1 - a2
```

> <|1 -> 0.605564, 2 -> -0.637237, 3 -> 0.366675, 4 -> -0.0596916, 
>    5 -> -0.735811, 6 -> -0.759424, 7 -> -0.383029, 8 -> -0.346902, 
>    9 -> 0.103136, 10 -> 0.492423|>

Plotting an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) is simple:

```
ListPlot[r]
```

[image]

Comment: Just a little warning/note: While in general I really like associations, I do sometimes find it difficult to work with them efficiently when I need access to both key and value. You can of course use `MapIndexed`, but then you have to take care of the `List` and `Key` wrappers...

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is to use `Table` to perform the operation element by element. To show how this would work, I will first make some data.

```
With[{n = 5},
  xs = Range[n];
  y1s = y1[#] & /@ xs;
  data1 = Transpose[{xs, y1s}];
  y2s = y2[#] & /@ xs;
  data2 = Transpose[{xs, y2s}]];
```

This produces two list like so.

```
data1
```

> `{{1, y1[1]}, {2, y1[2]}, {3, y1[3]}, {4, y1[4]}, {5, y1[5]}}`

```
data2
```

> `{{1, y2[1]}, {2, y2[2]}, {3, y2[3]}, {4, y2[4]}, {5, y2[5]}}`

Now the 1st element in each pair in either of the lists can be obtained with `Firsf` and the 2nd element with `Last`, so the general term for the result list is

```
{First[data1[[i]]], Last[data1[[i]]] - Last[data2[[i]]]}
```

Therefore,

```
Table[{First[data1[[i]]], Last[data1[[i]]] - Last[data2[[i]]]}, {i, Length[data1]}]
```

will do the job, giving

> ```
> {{1, y1[1] - y2[1]}, {2, y1[2] - y2[2]}, {3, y1[3] - y2[3]}, {4, y1[4] - y2[4]}, 
>  {5, y1[5] - y2[5]}}
> ```

A slightly more sophisticated approach with pure functions and `MapThread` is given by

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]] - #2[[2]]} &, {data1, data2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 list1 - list2.{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

```
lst1 = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, {5}];
lst2 = Array[{x[#], yy[#]} &, {5}];
lst1 - lst2.{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

> {{x[1], y[1] - yy[1]}, {x[2], y[2] - yy[2]}, {x[3], 
>     y[3] - yy[3]}, {x[4], y[4] - yy[4]}, {x[5], y[5] - yy[5]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
lis1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
lis2 = {{x1, y1'}, {x2, y2'}, {x3, y3'}};
lis3 = lis1 - lis2;
Transpose[{lis1[[All, 1]], lis3[[All, 2]]}]
```

> {{x1, y1 - y1'}, {x2, y2 - y2'}, {x3, y3 - y3'}}