# How to use syntax instead of double for loop

Tags: procedural-programming

I would like to find the distance between a point list (i.e `dalist`) and list of centers (i.e `framecenters`). I used the following script but it did not work. I do not want to use a double for loop. Any help is appreciated.

````
dalist = {{9, 6}, {5, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 
4}, {1, 1}, {7, 7}, {6, 8}, {5, 3}, {6, 9}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 
0}, {10, 7}, {6, 3}, {4, 0}, {9, 2}, {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 
8}, {0, 9}, {3, 4}, {0, 0}, {8, 5}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}, {2, 9}, {2, 
4}, {8, 4}, {7, 4}, {3, 6}, {7, 9}, {1, 9}, {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 
9}, {5, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0, 6}, {10, 3}, {9, 6}, {8, 
7}, {7, 6}, {7, 3}, {8, 9}, {7.5, 9}, {6.5, 9}, {7, 9}, {1, 
5}, {2, 6}, {1, 10}, {0.5, 8}, {1.5, 8}, {0.5, 7}, {1.5, 7}, {0.5,
 6}, {1.5, 6}, {0.5, 5}, {1.5, 5}, {0.5, 4}, {1.5, 4}, {0.5, 
9}, {1.5, 9}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}, {8, 4}, {8, 3}, {9,
 5}, {9, 3}, {7.5, 3}, {8.5, 3}, {9.5, 4}, {8.5, 4}, {9.5, 
4}, {7.5, 4}, {9.5, 4}};

frameCenters = {{1, 10}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}};
filter1[list_, peanut_] := EuclideanDistance[#, peanut] &
filter1[dalist, #] & /@ frameCenters  ```
````

Comment: If `dalist` and `frameCenters` are both lists of `{x,y}` coordinates, you might use `Outer[EuclideanDistance, dalist, frameCenters]`.  See [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

Comment: Thank you! But why it just shows a list of the list. {{{{8, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 5}}, {{5, 4}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}}}....}. Also, my objective was to learn how to use functions and syntaxes so it would be great if you can modify the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you're looking to compute the *distance matrix* of those two sets of vectors. This can be done, as Jason says, using `Outer`. It can also be done using the built-in function `DistanceMatrix`:

```
dm1 = Outer[EuclideanDistance, dalist, frameCenters, 1];
dm2 = DistanceMatrix[dalist, frameCenters];
dm1 == dm2
```

> True

The same can also be achieved using `Table`:

```
Table[
 EuclideanDistance[u, v],
 {u, dalist},
 {v, frameCenters}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you both! It is solved. But Mathematica has hundreds of these functions. How someone knows if these functions are available to use. It is not possible to find the required function with just a simple googling, I believe. That is why I thought maybe using basic functions are handier.

Comment: Still, if someone can modify the function is really appreciated.

Comment: @MehdiEbadi I added an example using `Table`, which I think is perhaps the easiest to understand solution. Your way is not really a natural way of doing it. You would have to have another `Map` in there to map over both lists, not just one. You could have found these functions with Google if you had known about the name "distance matrix", I think, without it, it might be difficult. `Outer` and `Table` are both frequently used functions that you will learn by heart if you keep using Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you C.E.!

Comment: @MehdiEbadi It's my pleasure to help.

Comment: I have a quick question C.E and appreciate your response. What does " level n in Listi" mean in the Outer function.

Comment: @MehdiEbadi It's difficult to explain in a comment, there are some good answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15577/731) about the general concept of levels.